# Change keyboard layout when running from USB

Tags: keyboard

I run Ubuntu 12.04 temporarily from USB made with unetbootin (because not allowed to install to this machine).
Machine has Finnish keyboard. How do I get the right keyboard layout. (System settings has only US keyboard available.)

Answer (score 0):

To change the layout, you can do that from terminal, so for example if you want to use English US, and Finish, you would just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle us,fi
```

Below is a list of the 2 letter country codes if needed.

```
Code    Country Name
AF  AFGHANISTAN
AX  ÅLAND ISLANDS
AL  ALBANIA
DZ  ALGERIA
AS  AMERICAN SAMOA
AD  ANDORRA
AO  ANGOLA
AI  ANGUILLA
AQ  ANTARCTICA
AG  ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA
AR  ARGENTINA
AM  ARMENIA
AW  ARUBA
AU  AUSTRALIA
AT  AUSTRIA
AZ  AZERBAIJAN
BS  BAHAMAS
BH  BAHRAIN
BD  BANGLADESH
BB  BARBADOS
BY  BELARUS
BE  BELGIUM
BZ  BELIZE
BJ  BENIN
BM  BERMUDA
BT  BHUTAN
BO  BOLIVIA, PLURINATIONAL STATE OF
BQ  BONAIRE, SINT EUSTATIUS AND SABA
BA  BOSNIA AND HERZEGOVINA
BW  BOTSWANA
BV  BOUVET ISLAND
BR  BRAZIL
IO  BRITISH INDIAN OCEAN TERRITORY
BN  BRUNEI DARUSSALAM
BG  BULGARIA
BF  BURKINA FASO
BI  BURUNDI
KH  CAMBODIA
CM  CAMEROON
CA  CANADA
CV  CAPE VERDE
KY  CAYMAN ISLANDS
CF  CENTRAL AFRICAN REPUBLIC
TD  CHAD
CL  CHILE
CN  CHINA
CX  CHRISTMAS ISLAND
CC  COCOS (KEELING) ISLANDS
CO  COLOMBIA
KM  COMOROS
CG  CONGO
CD  CONGO, THE DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE
CK  COOK ISLANDS
CR  COSTA RICA
CI  CÔTE D'IVOIRE
HR  CROATIA
CU  CUBA
CW  CURAÇAO
CY  CYPRUS
CZ  CZECH REPUBLIC
DK  DENMARK
DJ  DJIBOUTI
DM  DOMINICA
DO  DOMINICAN REPUBLIC
EC  ECUADOR
EG  EGYPT
SV  EL SALVADOR
GQ  EQUATORIAL GUINEA
ER  ERITREA
EE  ESTONIA
ET  ETHIOPIA
FK  FALKLAND ISLANDS (MALVINAS)
FO  FAROE ISLANDS
FJ  FIJI
FI  FINLAND
FR  FRANCE
GF  FRENCH GUIANA
PF  FRENCH POLYNESIA
TF  FRENCH SOUTHERN TERRITORIES
GA  GABON
GM  GAMBIA
GE  GEORGIA
DE  GERMANY
GH  GHANA
GI  GIBRALTAR
GR  GREECE
GL  GREENLAND
GD  GRENADA
GP  GUADELOUPE
GU  GUAM
GT  GUATEMALA
GG  GUERNSEY
GN  GUINEA
GW  GUINEA-BISSAU
GY  GUYANA
HT  HAITI
HM  HEARD ISLAND AND MCDONALD ISLANDS
VA  HOLY SEE (VATICAN CITY STATE)
HN  HONDURAS
HK  HONG KONG
HU  HUNGARY
IS  ICELAND
IN  INDIA
ID  INDONESIA
IR  IRAN, ISLAMIC REPUBLIC OF
IQ  IRAQ
IE  IRELAND
IM  ISLE OF MAN
IL  ISRAEL
IT  ITALY
JM  JAMAICA
JP  JAPAN
JE  JERSEY
JO  JORDAN
KZ  KAZAKHSTAN
KE  KENYA
KI  KIRIBATI
KP  KOREA, DEMOCRATIC PEOPLE'S REPUBLIC OF
KR  KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
KW  KUWAIT
KG  KYRGYZSTAN
LA  LAO PEOPLE'S DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC
LV  LATVIA
LB  LEBANON
LS  LESOTHO
LR  LIBERIA
LY  LIBYA
LI  LIECHTENSTEIN
LT  LITHUANIA
LU  LUXEMBOURG
MO  MACAO
MK  MACEDONIA, THE FORMER YUGOSLAV REPUBLIC OF
MG  MADAGASCAR
MW  MALAWI
MY  MALAYSIA
MV  MALDIVES
ML  MALI
MT  MALTA
MH  MARSHALL ISLANDS
MQ  MARTINIQUE
MR  MAURITANIA
MU  MAURITIUS
YT  MAYOTTE
MX  MEXICO
FM  MICRONESIA, FEDERATED STATES OF
MD  MOLDOVA, REPUBLIC OF
MC  MONACO
MN  MONGOLIA
ME  MONTENEGRO
MS  MONTSERRAT
MA  MOROCCO
MZ  MOZAMBIQUE
MM  MYANMAR
NA  NAMIBIA
NR  NAURU
NP  NEPAL
NL  NETHERLANDS
NC  NEW CALEDONIA
NZ  NEW ZEALAND
NI  NICARAGUA
NE  NIGER
NG  NIGERIA
NU  NIUE
NF  NORFOLK ISLAND
MP  NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS
NO  NORWAY
OM  OMAN
PK  PAKISTAN
PW  PALAU
PS  PALESTINE, STATE OF
PA  PANAMA
PG  PAPUA NEW GUINEA
PY  PARAGUAY
PE  PERU
PH  PHILIPPINES
PN  PITCAIRN
PL  POLAND
PT  PORTUGAL
PR  PUERTO RICO
QA  QATAR
RE  RÉUNION
RO  ROMANIA
RU  RUSSIAN FEDERATION
RW  RWANDA
BL  SAINT BARTHÉLEMY
SH  SAINT HELENA, ASCENSION AND TRISTAN DA CUNHA
KN  SAINT KITTS AND NEVIS
LC  SAINT LUCIA
MF  SAINT MARTIN (FRENCH PART)
PM  SAINT PIERRE AND MIQUELON
VC  SAINT VINCENT AND THE GRENADINES
WS  SAMOA
SM  SAN MARINO
ST  SAO TOME AND PRINCIPE
SA  SAUDI ARABIA
SN  SENEGAL
RS  SERBIA
SC  SEYCHELLES
SL  SIERRA LEONE
SG  SINGAPORE
SX  SINT MAARTEN (DUTCH PART)
SK  SLOVAKIA
SI  SLOVENIA
SB  SOLOMON ISLANDS
SO  SOMALIA
ZA  SOUTH AFRICA
GS  SOUTH GEORGIA AND THE SOUTH SANDWICH ISLANDS
SS  SOUTH SUDAN
ES  SPAIN
LK  SRI LANKA
SD  SUDAN
SR  SURINAME
SJ  SVALBARD AND JAN MAYEN
SZ  SWAZILAND
SE  SWEDEN
CH  SWITZERLAND
SY  SYRIAN ARAB REPUBLIC
TW  TAIWAN, PROVINCE OF CHINA
TJ  TAJIKISTAN
TZ  TANZANIA, UNITED REPUBLIC OF
TH  THAILAND
TL  TIMOR-LESTE
TG  TOGO
TK  TOKELAU
TO  TONGA
TT  TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO
TN  TUNISIA
TR  TURKEY
TM  TURKMENISTAN
TC  TURKS AND CAICOS ISLANDS
TV  TUVALU
UG  UGANDA
UA  UKRAINE
AE  UNITED ARAB EMIRATES
GB  UNITED KINGDOM
US  UNITED STATES
UM  UNITED STATES MINOR OUTLYING ISLANDS
UY  URUGUAY
UZ  UZBEKISTAN
VU  VANUATU
VE  VENEZUELA, BOLIVARIAN REPUBLIC OF
VN  VIET NAM
VG  VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH
VI  VIRGIN ISLANDS, U.S.
WF  WALLIS AND FUTUNA
EH  WESTERN SAHARA
YE  YEMEN
ZM  ZAMBIA
ZW  ZIMBABWE
```